# copying escaped variable to txt file batch

Tags: cmd, escaping

heres what i want to do.
i have a variable name a
if i do

```
echo %a% >txt.txt
```

it will store value of a

what i want to store in a is the text

```
%a%
```

as such.

tried

```
%%a%% 
^%a^% 
%%%a%%% 
%%%^ a^ %%
```

1. - highlights the first three chars
2. - highlights everthing except first ^
3. - gave only one % as output
4. - same as above

Comment: No Need got the answer, used set per=%% and then echo %per%a%per%

Comment: %%a%% should have worked. Not sure what you mean by `highlight`

Comment: `echo %%a%%>txt.txt` works. Why not for you?

Comment: i meant that it got used as a variable (it gets highlighted in notepad++)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you and highlight the variable:

```
echo %%a%%>txt.bat & notepad++ txt.bat
```

or, more advanced:

```
echo %%a%%>txt.cmd & notepad++ txt.cmd
```